# How to default status filter in TortoiseHG Workbench?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, workbench

The image below shows the list of filters in the file list of TortoiseHG Workbench.

Everytime I use it have to check / uncheck items in this list. eg: `? unknown` needs to be de-selected so those files will not be shown.

[image]

Can I set default values for this? Such as in the configuration file `~/.hgrc` for instance?

Or, is there other methods?

Comment: Why don't you just ignore files you don't want to see there?

Comment: @JacekSzumigaj I think he means the list of options he has shown, not the list of files.

Comment: exactly, thats right

Comment: @DaveInCaz yes, I know. But I think the intension was to hide unwanted files ;)

Comment: @JacekSzumigaj you meant it a an alternative approach, I see what you mean. Thanks. But I don't know if hgignore could work for all "unknown" files...

Comment: @JacekSzumigaj, I don't want to add instructions for ignoring files. Because this will create problems with the sorting and the work of a large number of files in the project through the terminal console.